# PHP CodeSniffer: indentation of 2 is ignored, it just checks 4

Tags: php, code-quality

```
# phpcs --version
PHP_CodeSniffer version 1.3.3 (stable) by Squiz Pty Ltd. (http://www.squiz.net)
#
```

Trying to do this:

```
phpcs --tab-width=2 includes/json/item/categorie.php 
FOUND 29 ERROR(S) AND 3 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 24 LINE(S)
```

Doesn't work.
This doesn't work too:

```
phpcs includes/json/item/categorie.php --tab-width=2
FOUND 29 ERROR(S) AND 3 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 24 LINE(S)
```

If I indent the file with 4 spaces (which I don't want):

```
phpcs --tab-width=2 includes/json/item/categorie.php 
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AND 3 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 17 LINE(S)
phpcs --tab-width=4 includes/json/item/categorie.php 
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AND 3 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 17 LINE(S)
phpcs --tab-width=50 includes/json/item/categorie.php 
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AND 3 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 17 LINE(S)
phpcs includes/json/item/categorie.php --tab-width=50 
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AND 3 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 17 LINE(S)
```

So it's totally ignored. It this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad:

```
# phpcs --help
Usage: phpcs [-nwlsapvi] [-d key[=value]]
        ...blabla...
        <tabWidth>    The number of spaces each tab represents
        ...blabla...
```

This means "when there's the tab character, how many spaces does it represent".

There's nothing to do with indentation of "4" which seems to be hard-coded.